# What is the Big theta of $(\log n)^2+2n+4n+\log n + 50$?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, big-o-notation

$f(n)=(\log n)^2+2n+4n+\log n + 50$

I am trying to mathematically prove that $f(n)$ falls under some time complexity big theta. My guess is that it is $(\log n)^2$ because it is the dominant term.

I need to come to the conclusion of $f(n)\leq C(\log n)^2$, for some positive constant $C$ and $x\geq k$.

What I have tried is:

$(\log n)^2+\log n \leq 2(\log n)^2$

I want to add $6n + 50$ to both sides, but cannot find the constant $c$ by algebra in $c(\log n)^2$.

I have just tried putting random values of $c$ to make $c(\log n)^2 \geq 6n$ true and $c=100$ works for $n$ greater than some value, but is there a mathematical way of finding this value of $c$ and therefore finding the big theta of this function?

-----------------------------------------------

Additional try:

I have changed my thought and I think $n$ is the dominant term because polylogarithms grow slower than polynomial functions, $n^b$ where $b > 0$.

And so

$(\log n)^2 + \log n \leq 2n$

$(\log n)^2 + \log n + 6n + 50 \leq 9n$ for $n \geq 50$.

And, for the big Omega, it is obvious that $(\log n)^2 + \log n + 6n + 50 \geq 6n$

Thus, we can see that $f(n) \in \theta(n)$.

But I'm not sure as to if I have to prove that the polylogarithm $(\log n)^2$ grows slower than the linear function $n$ to complete the reasoning. Will that include the use of L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @quantitative_ thank you for your comment. But I came to think that $6n$ may be the dominant term as polynomials grow faster than logarithms? and I think for large $n$, $6n$ eventually beats $(\log n)^2$..

Comment: You're correct, I overlooked that. $(\log n)^c = O(n)$ for any $c > 0$. So you just have to prove that for constants, $g, c, n_0$ that $g \cdot n \leq f(n) \leq c \cdot n$ for $g \geq 0$, $c \geq 0$, $n \geq n_0 $

Comment: @quantitative_ Thanks again. Could you check my edited question, I have added my working out. And, I don't know if I have to prove the fact that the polylogarithm grows slower than the linear function or should the above be enough for the answer?

Comment: No problem. The above edited question looks good. You do not have to prove that $(\log n)^2 \in O(n)$ separately to show that $f(n) \in O(n)$. You simply have to show that the entire function, $f(n) \in O(n)$ by demonstrating that there exists constants, $c, n_0$ ($c > 0) such that $f(n) \leq cn$ for all $n \geq n_0$ which you correctly did with $n_0 = 50$. Similarly for the lower bound.

Comment: Every function $f(n)$ satisfies $f(n) = \Theta(f(n))$.